# Loop through cells to generate a set of named ranges in VBA / Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tracker at my work which pulls information from a report, the information then needs to be extracted per user with a named range. Doing it manually is a long and tedious process - I was wondering if there was a way to get it to automatically generate the named ranges based on the values between two cells in Column A.

The values in Column A do change and aren't numbered (but they always follow the same format). So ideally it would just search for the next non-empty cell.

The code below is what's being used to generate the named range, but I was wondering if it was possible to pre-fill USER1, USER2, RANGE_NAME_USER1 etc based on the next non-empty cell so it generates all the ranges needed.

So once it's done with USER1, it will then be USER2, USER3, RANGE_NAME_USER2 etc?

I've tried some while loops and such but I can't seem to figure out how to change the values of "USER1", "USER2" to automatically know what to do.

```
Sub SelectBetween()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    findrow = Range("A:A").Find("USER1", Range("A1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("USER2", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
    Range("B" & findrow + 1 & ":Q" & findrow2 - 1).Select
    Selection.Name = "RANGE_NAME_USER1"
errhandler:
Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Can't find the cells! Please check!"
End Sub
```

The idea is that once it's found USER1 and allocated a named range to it, it would repeat the code but be similar to:

```
Sub SelectBetween()
    Dim findrow As Long, findrow2 As Long
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    findrow = Range("A:A").Find("USER2", Range("A1")).Row
    findrow2 = Range("A:A").Find("USER3", Range("A" & findrow)).Row
    Range("B" & findrow + 1 & ":Q" & findrow2 - 1).Select
    Selection.Name = "RANGE_NAME_USER2"
errhandler:
Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Can't find the cells! Please check!"
End Sub
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Think this does what you want. It loops through a list of the range names so adjust to suit, ditto sheet name.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind1 As Range, rFind2 As Range, vNames As Variant, i As Long

vNames = Array("USER1", "USER2", "USER3", "RANGE_NAME_USER2")

With Sheet1.Columns(1)
    Set rFind1 = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    For i = LBound(vNames) To UBound(vNames) - 1
        Set rFind1 = .Find(What:=vNames(i), After:=rFind1, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind1 Is Nothing Then
            Set rFind2 = .Find(What:=vNames(i + 1), After:=rFind1)
            If Not rFind2 Is Nothing Then
                .Range("B" & rFind1.Row + 1 & ":Q" & rFind2.Row - 1).Name = vNames(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("B" & rFind2.Row + 1 & ":Q" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Name = vNames(UBound(vNames))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That could work though we have a changing task force and the array will be dynamic/vary - but can work around that - unless there's a way to automatically create an array? I've got one set up on a separate sheet with a list of all the names, pulled from the tracker. There's over 100+ users, and it can change. I'm getting a runtime error 13, type mismatch - will check through the code though.

Comment: Yes you could loop through a range instead. Which line errors? I don't think I made provision for missing names.

Comment: When I add an array to test it, it errors once it gets to this the second time:
`Set rFind1 = .Find(What:=vNames(i), After:=rFind1, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

The way the report is laid out is making this very difficult for me to get my head around. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yZtsfAz0YfuJVPgd2l2cmviYmWu1Qswy9l956AucgEk/edit?usp=sharing - this is effectively what the report looks like.

The users are in A and the ranges I need to create per user start in B to I (in this example).

Comment: What are your actual values in column A - a named range can't contain a space (not causing the error you mention). Are the values you are looping through simply those in column A?

Comment: They are, but I amended them in the table for testing the code. If it works when I amend the values in column A, I could set up some formula and separate macros to pull it to another sheet/changing the values. The issue I have is this report is generated every day and will automatically change the values back to what you see currently in A

Comment: Works for me on your file (with one small change above). Do some debugging, check the values when it errors, whether it does any ranges etc.

Comment: Ah, yes. This seems to be working now! Thank you very much - you've made my life easier!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users are sorted and user names are valid as part of a range name, and that you want all user names to be created as range names.

```
Sub SetUserRanges()

    Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet
    Dim usr, rngUsers As Range, n As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set rngUsers = sht.Range(sht.Range("A2"), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set c = rngUsers.Cells(1)
    Do While c.Row <= rngUsers.Cells(rngUsers.Cells.Count).Row

        usr = c.Value 'current user
        n = Application.CountIf(rngUsers, usr)

        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(n, 16).Name = Rangename(usr)

        Set c = c.Offset(n, 0)
    Loop

End Sub

'Convert a username formatted as "Agent ####: LastName, FirstName" into 
' "FirstName_LastName"
Function Rangename(usr As String) As String
    Dim arr
    'split on ":" then split second part on ","
    arr = Split(Split(usr, ":")(1), ",")
    Rangename = Trim(arr(1)) & "_" & Trim(arr(0))
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, as the range will vary (though is always between the two users) and aren't valid as a range name. They're all formatted as: Agent ####: LastName, FirstName.

I've already ran a conversion formula (subtitute etc) in Excel to change them to valid range names - though I can't for the life of me think of a way to parse this into VBA. I'm really having a blank moment!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the range will vary" - this code should account for that.  If you need to create a mapping between usernames and range names you can do that on a worksheet and use VLOOKUP to get the range name from the username.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear/made no sense.

The user names aren't laid out as valid range names and they can't be sorted/user names change every day on each report. I've already got the range name based on each user name but unsure how to then have the macro know when each user stops and the next starts, in order to then grab a range from it. 

For reference, the user names that I need the range generating from are formatting as _Agent ####: LastName, FirstName_ and the range names I have generating is _FirstNameLastName_

Your code works - but not with the reports that get generated :(

Comment: See edit for how to create the range name from the user name

Comment: Perfect thank you! I should be able to use this to get what I need!

Comment: Just saw your sample file - that's totally different from what I'd thought you were dealing with and explains your original approach....

Comment: Oh haha - can you think of an easier way to do what I was hoping as I'ev taken both codes and have basically butchered them to do what I want, but I'd like it to be cleaner if possible